# How to find the region of uniform convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

How would I go about finding the region of uniform convergence for $\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{2^4+x^4}+\frac{1}{3^4+x^6}+...$?

Thank you

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ or in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: It's not stated in the question, but I'm assuming $\mathbb{R}$ since we haven't done anything on complex numbers for this module.

Comment: For any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$, $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n^4+x^{2n}}$ is a positive function bounded by $\frac{1}{n^4}$. Since $\frac{1}{n^4}$ is summable over $n\geq 1$, the region of uniform convergence is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see. Could you explain how I would find the region of uniform convergence of a function? Because I have a few other similar questions and I have no idea how to start. One of the other questions is $e^{-x}+2^{p}e^{-2x}$.

Comment: It is not quite correct to speak of "the region of uniform convergence". Uniform convergence is not defined point-wise, but with respect to some region. So there need not be some maximal region where it occurs. For example $f_n(x) = x^{-n}$ converges uniformly on any interval $[a,b]$ with $-1 < a < b < 1$. But it does not converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$.